# mongodb: get top x rankings(count) of occurrences in documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents that have general geo location information. I am trying get the top x cities for example.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("593b6a7068c4281a3f7702c5"), 
    "clientID" : "1000000000", 
    "session_id" : "I9Ak2k1taOGHU0Z0000000000", 
    "location" : {
        "country" : "United States", 
        "city" : "Seattle", 
        "postal" : "98105", 
        "traits" : null, 
        "local" : "America/Los_Angeles"
    }, 
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-09T21:12:56.819+0000"), 
    "action" : "PLAY",....
}
```

I am fairly new to mongo, coming from sql. I was hoping to get this done using aggregation & without doing it in code after I get a range of docs returned.

I figured out how to group these documents by session_id and such I now just need to add the instance of city count sorted descending and just display those cities.

my group query:

```
db.Playerstats.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1 for tests
        {
            $match: {
                clientID: "1000000000"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id : "$session_id", 
                start: { $first: "$dateTime"},
                stop: { $last: "$dateTime"},
                eventID : { $addToSet: "$eventID"},
                status : { $addToSet: "$eventStatus"},
                browser: { $addToSet: "$browser.userAgent"},
                OS : { $addToSet: "$browser.platform"},
                city : { $addToSet: "location.city"},
                p2pData : { $sum: "$p2p.totalVerifiedBytes"},
                actions : { $addToSet: "$action"}
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $sort: {
                startDate: -1
            }
        },
    ],
);
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: What have you tried? There is nothing in the question that shows any attempt. If you show an attempt then we can guide you in the parts you do not understand. But there are plenty of examples out there to read. [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

Comment: I have tried a {
   $group: {
    _id: {
              cust_id: "$city",
              count: {???}
           }
   }
  },
after stage 3 of my query as I posted.
but I am lost as to how to sum those counts from the grouping

Comment: figured it out.. $group: {
    _id: "$city",
       count: { $sum: 1 }
           
   }
just had it wrapped wrong. TY

Comment: Thanks for the nudge and the link Neil

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add another grouping to the query for the cities and get that count. now I can add a limit and sorting to round it out.

```
{
    $group: {
    _id: "$city",
     count: { $sum: 1 }             
    }
}
```